# Why doesn't .charAt() combined with .replace() solve this javascript algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question**

Perform a search and replace on the sentence using the arguments provided and return the new sentence.

First argument is the sentence to perform the search and replace on.

Second argument is the word that you will be replacing (before).

Third argument is what you will be replacing the second argument with (after).

Note
Preserve the case of the first character in the original word when you are replacing it. For example if you mean to replace the word "Book" with the word "dog", it should be replaced as "Dog"

**My Code**

```js
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  let upperCase = [true]; 
  let regex = /^[A-Z]/
  if(regex.test(before)==true){
    upperCase[0] = true;
  } else {
    upperCase[0] = false;
  }
  let replacement = [after];
  if(upperCase[0] == true){
    replacement[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  } else {
    replacement[0].charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  }

   return str.replace(before, replacement[0]);
}

console.log(myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped"));

console.log(myReplace("Let us get back to more Coding", "Coding", "algorithms"))
```

Comment: What do you think/hope that `replacement[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();` does? Strings are immutable.

Comment: Why are you using arrays? Is there any reason that I am missing?

Comment: @Sid may have this wrong, but because I can edit an array globally from inside a function because it is an object. But not so with a variable

Comment: @Andreas functions like .toUpperCase() only work on strings as far as I am aware

Comment: Yes, and that's the "problem". Strings are immutable. You cannot modify a character in a string in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code a little bit.

Strings are immutable so `replacement[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase();` won't work as you might expect.

```
function toUpperCaseFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function toLowerCaseFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  const regex = /^[A-Z]/
  const upperCase = regex.test(before);
  const replacement = upperCase ? 
     toUpperCaseFirstLetter(after)
     : toLowerCaseFirstLetter(after);

  return str.replace(before, replacement);
}

console.log(myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "Leaped"));

console.log(myReplace("Let us get back to more Coding", "Coding", "algorithms"))
```

Adding @Andreas comment to the answer

> "I don't see how that is different to what I have done". Sid takes the
> first characters, changes the case, adds the rest of the string and
> returns that newly constructed string as the result. You're changing
> the case of the first character and then throw that character away -
> leaving the source string unmodified.
> @Andreas

Comment: Here is what I don't undeerstand about how you ave used CharAt().toUpperCase(): I don't see how that is different to what I have done with that aspect of the code (purely in terms of mutability - adding the slice makes sense for example)

Comment: Both `charAt` and `toUpperCase` return a new string, they don't replace the chars in the original string. So what the code is doing is creating a new string from the first char and then concatenates it to the rest of the string, resulting in a new string.  @AndrewNeedsHelp

Comment: _"I don't see how that is different to what I have done"_. Sid takes the first characters, changes the case, adds the rest of the string and returns that newly constructed string as the result. You're changing the case of the first character and then throw that character away - leaving the source string unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of fixing the specific synatax that I used, on the basis of @sid comment. Here is my solution that solves the problem:

```js
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  let upperCase = [true]; 
  let regex = /^[A-Z]/
  if(regex.test(before)==true){
    upperCase[0] = true;
  } else {
    upperCase[0] = false;
  }
  let replacement = [after];

  if(upperCase[0] == true){
   let a = replacement[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + after.slice(1,);
   replacement[0] = a;
  } else {
    let a = replacement[0].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + after.slice(1,);
    replacement[0] = a; 
  }

   return str.replace(before, replacement[0]);
}

console.log(myReplace("A quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "jumped", "leaped"));

console.log(myReplace("Let us get back to more Coding", "Coding", "algorithms"))
```